# Visual Studio 2015 : angular 2 @component unable to resolve signature of class decorator

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-2015

Using Visual studio 2015 and as you can see I'm trying to define my decorator on top of my class. However when I hit build I'm getting the error ..

Build:Unable to resolve signature of class decorator when called as an expression

```
import { Component } from "angular2/core";
import { Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS } from "angular2/http";
import "rxjs/Rx";
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from "angular2/router"; // RouteConfig

import { SearchService } from './search/search.service';
import { SearchComponent } from './search/search.component';
import { SiteComponent } from './site/site.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<div>testing</div>',
    directives: [],
    providers: [SearchService, HTTP_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PROVIDERS]
})
export class AppComponent {
    pageTitle: string = "My App"
}
```

The typescripttoolsversion is set to 1.8 in mycsproj file. I'm using npm to install my dependencies.

> ```
> "dependencies": {
>     "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
>     "systemjs": "0.19.26",
>     "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
>     "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
>     "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2",
>     "zone.js": "0.6.10",
>     "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
> },
> "devDependencies": {
>     "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
>     "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
>     "typescript": "^1.8.10",
>     "typings": "^0.7.12"
> }
> ```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there any other information I can give?

Answer (score 0):

It would be strongly recommended that you upgrade to the latest version of Angular 2, which is currently on release candidate 4.  This should help as the latest version has official guides available for Visual Studio.  You can do this by updating your package.json.  Make sure to include the additional configuration files from the quickstart guide (link below).  You will also need to update your systemjs loader and HTML to reflect the updated angular name.  There is also an additional tutorial for configuring Angular 2 in Visual Studio 2015.

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

HTML:

`import { Component } from '@angular/core';`

Source: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Visual Studio 2015 Quickstart: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html